# Adding links to buttons in a slider

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React :)
I need help adding links to each button for each item in a carousel, here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/varulv/tuhebzgL/latest/

```
const slideData = [
{
  index: 0,
  headline: 'CNN',
  button: 'Read More',
  src: 'assets/media/uploads/news13.jpg' },
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the property `link` in your data, add it in your props

```
const { src, button, link, headline, index } = this.props.slide;
```

And then create your button element like this:

```
React.createElement("button", { className: "slide__action btn" }, React.createElement("a", {href: link},
button));
```

I have edited your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kd6e0nqa/20/) (the links are dummy)